# NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Keep getting this error in my discord bot cog. I use message.author in other cogs just fine just with events not commands.

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('profiles.json', 'r') as f:
        profiles = json.load(f)

    await update_profile(profiles, member)

    with open('profiles.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(profiles, f, indent=2)

@commands.command(name='my', pass_context=True)
async def my(self, ctx):

    with open('profiles.json', 'r') as x:
        profiles = json.load(x)

    await self.update_profile(profiles, ctx.message.author)

    with open('profiles.json', 'w') as x:
        json.dump(profiles, x, indent=2)


async def update_profile(self, user, message):
        profile_params = {'Xbox Live': 'xbl', 'PSN': 'psn', 'Steam ID': 'stm','Nintendo Friend Code': 'nfc'}
        msg = ctx.message
        bmsg = msg[4:7]
        emsg = msg[8:]
        if not user.name in users and not user.bot:
            do some stuff
```

This is the error i get I have tried many work arounds with this I can not find anything that will fix this issue

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Discord Bot\profiles.py", line 28, in my
    await self.update_profile(profiles, ctx.message.author)
  File "D:\Discord Bot\profiles.py", line 36, in update_profile
    msg = ctx.message
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

I have tried many work arounds searching for similar issues. I have noticed that it works fine in the main py file and it also works fine in a cog in the on_message event. It only does not work when I use it inside a @commands.command command function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do You Send an Embed as a DM with Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127860/how-do-you-send-an-embed-as-a-dm-with-discord-py)

Comment: Fix your indentation please, it's difficult to tell which scope things are defined in at the moment.  That said, your `update_profile` coroutine doesn't make much sense.  There is a `message` argument, which you can use inside `update_profile`, but you aren't actually passing a message.  You aren't passing a `ctx` object, so you can't use it in the coroutine.  What is that coroutine supposed to do?

Comment: I want the coroutine to take a part of the command which will be /my and store it in a user profile json file. basically i want the command /my xbl namehere to update the json file Xbox Live: namehere. so i can make another command for users to call on to get the info that a user has added

Comment: Add the python tag please

Comment: @Patrick. If you add the python tag, I'll hammer it.

Comment: What scope is your `my()` function in? What class? Where is it getting `self` from? Judging by the error, the function is being passed a context as the first parameter, which tells me that the context into `self`,  and then erroring when it isn't also passed a `ctx`

Comment: According to that self.message.author should work, but that also doesnt work i get the error that self is not defined. Without the @ decorator and moved the broken code to the on_messsge event it will work fine